# Unable to locate publishable resources error using ParsedownServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, composer-php, gitignore, parsedown

I am using the Parsedown for Laravel library and have installed using composer with the following command:

```
composer require parsedown/laravel
```

I'd like to set line breaks enabled to true and am following the documentation instruction:

```
'breaks_enabled' => true,
```

You can overwrite these values by publishing the config/parsedown.php file with the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Parsedown\Providers\ParsedownServiceProvider"
```

running this command I receive the following error:

```
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.
```

The change works locally when tested however when deployed to server the change does not take effect as the vendor directory used by composer to manage libraries is added to .gitignore it does make it through to source control.

What I have tried reading other posts:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
```

which still returns me the same issue

Comment: Do you mean that when you run `vendor:publish` locally it works but doesn't work on production server

Comment: good question, that was me running the command locally

Comment: Let me understand correctly - on local machine no error but production server gives error right?

Comment: local machine returns error; production server exhibits no change

Comment: Try removing the vendor directory and composer install again on local machine

Comment: please close the terminal and open and try again